# Install canon ir1435 network printer

Tags: printing, canon

I am new to Ubuntu. I am trying to install cannon image runner 1435 network printer. I am unable to do so. Please help me. 
Thanks to all in advance

Comment: How you are trying to install the printer. What error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

At this time, the Canon ImageRunner 1435 Printer is not supported directly by CUPS:

http://www.openprinting.org/printers

There is however a deb package that may work, provided by the Manufaturer:

http://files.canon-europe.com/files/soft45505/Software/CQue_v3.0.2_Linux_64_EN.deb

Once you've downloaded it, you can install it with your favorite package manager, or from the command line like this:

`sudo dpkg -i CQue_v3.0.2_Linux_64_EN.deb`

I hope this helps :)